# ansible error: from version import VERSION\nImportError: No module named version\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}

Tags: python, ansible, juniper

I have tried to troubleshoot it but could not do it.
Very basic ansible code but I am getting this error:

```
---
- name: backup devices
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    systime: "{{ ansible_date_time.time | replace(':','-') }}"
  tasks:
     - debug: var=ansible_date_time.time
     - debug: var=systime
```

~
~

When I execude it:

PLAY [backup devices] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named version
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1525842798.74-216965251483917/setup.py\", line 3, in \n    from version import VERSION\nImportError: No module named version\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/vagrant/aja/conf-backup3.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Any one can help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: When I disable gather facts it is being executed :

Comment: What version of ansible are you using?

Comment: 2.5.1 and 2.3.2

Comment: same code works in my mac but not in ubuntu 16.4

Comment: This code works fine on my machine as well. Can you run your playbook with -vvv option?